# How to initialize immutable globals with non-const initializer in Rust?

Tags: rust, static, initialization

I am trying to get a variable that is only initialized once, at runtime.
In C/C++ `static` would be the keyword that I would be looking for, yet in Rust, it must be initialized by a constant.

`static mut` is unsafe, and I can see why, but it doesn't conceptually capture what I want, I want an immutable variable.

Take this trivial example of a tribonacci function:

```rs
static sqrt_33_mul_3: f64 = 3.0 * 33.0f64.powf(0.5);

static tribonacci_constant: f64 = 1.0
+ (19.0 - sqrt_33_mul_3).powf(1.0 / 3.0)
+ (19.0 + sqrt_33_mul_3).powf(1.0 / 3.0);

fn tribonacci(n: f64) -> f64 {
    return (
        (tribonacci_constant / 3.0).powf(n)
        / (
            (4.0 / 3.0)
            * tribonacci_constant
            - (1.0 / 9.0)
            * tribonacci_constant.powf(2.0) - 1.0
        )
    ).round();
}
```

I want the two static variables outside of the function to be initialized only once, and powf to not be called with every run of the function

I am incredibly new to Rust and do not know what may be common knowledge to the average, experienced user.

Is this possible, if so, how can it be done?

Comment: TL;DR, but seems you are looking for [lazy_static](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static)

Comment: The problem is that `f64::powf` is not a `const` function. There are some RFCs that I've been able to find for making most/all the floating-point functions const. Most had comments saying this was "difficult" but I was unable to work out exactly why. (I suspect it has to do with things like changing some hardware floating-point mode resulting in potential changes to the behaviour of these functions at run-time). I live in hope that something like this will eventually find its way into rust so that your code will "just work".

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can insert the variable definitions into the function. In general, static variables in a function should only be initialized once.

Comment: @Adam It doesn't matter where they are or aren't, they need to be initialized by a constant.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson That part I understand; that's why I had to come here to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `f64::powf` was a const function then the compiler should convert things like `3.0 * 33.0f64.powf(0.5)` down to a single fixed value.

While `lazy_static` can be used to solve this problem, there is a cost behind using lazy_statics, because they're designed to support more than just simple floating-point constants.

You can see this cost by benchmarking the two implementations using Criterion:

```
pub mod ls {
    use lazy_static::lazy_static; // 1.4.0

    lazy_static! {
        //TODO: Should this be a pow(1.0/3.0)?
        pub static ref cbrt_33_mul_3: f64 = 3.0 * 33.0f64.powf(0.5);
        
        pub static ref tribonacci_constant: f64 = 1.0
        + (19.0 - *cbrt_33_mul_3).powf(1.0 / 3.0)
        + (19.0 + *cbrt_33_mul_3).powf(1.0 / 3.0);
    }

    pub fn tribonacci(n: f64) -> f64 {
        return (
            (*tribonacci_constant / 3.0).powf(n)
            / (
                (4.0 / 3.0)
                * *tribonacci_constant
                - (1.0 / 9.0)
                * tribonacci_constant.powf(2.0) - 1.0
            )
        ).round();
    }
}

pub mod hc {
    pub fn tribonacci(n: f64) -> f64 {
        let p = 1.839286755214161;
        let s = 0.3362281169949411;
        return (s * p.powf(n)).round();
    }
}

fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    c.bench_function("trib 5.1 ls", |b| b.iter(|| ls::tribonacci(black_box(5.1))));
    c.bench_function("trib 5.1 hc", |b| b.iter(|| hc::tribonacci(black_box(5.1))));
}

criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

The cost is small, but may be significant if this is in your core loops.
On my machine, I get (after removing unrelated lines)

```
trib 5.1 ls             time:   [47.946 ns 48.832 ns 49.796 ns]                         
trib 5.1 hc             time:   [38.828 ns 39.898 ns 41.266 ns]
```

This is about a 20% difference.

If you don't like having hardcoded constants in your code, you can actually generate these at build time using a `build.rs` script.

My complete example for benchmarking looks like this:

**build.rs**

```
use std::env;
use std::fs;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let out_dir = env::var_os("OUT_DIR").unwrap();
    let dest_path = Path::new(&out_dir).join("constants.rs");

    //TODO: Should this be a pow(1.0/3.0)?
    let cbrt_33_mul_3: f64 = 3.0 * 33.0f64.powf(0.5);
    
    let tribonacci_constant: f64 = 1.0 
        + (19.0 - cbrt_33_mul_3).powf(1.0 / 3.0)
        + (19.0 + cbrt_33_mul_3).powf(1.0 / 3.0);

    let p = tribonacci_constant / 3.0;
    let s = 1.0 / (
        (4.0 / 3.0)
        * tribonacci_constant
        - (1.0 / 9.0)
        * tribonacci_constant.powf(2.0) - 1.0
    );

    fs::write(
        &dest_path,
        format!("\
        pub mod tribonacci {{\n\
            pub const P: f64 = {:.32};\n\
            pub const S: f64 = {:.32};\n\
        }}\n", p, s)
    ).unwrap();
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=build.rs");
}
```

**src/lib.rs**

```
pub mod constants {
    include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/constants.rs"));
}

pub mod ls {
    use lazy_static::lazy_static; // 1.4.0

    lazy_static! {
        //TODO: Should this be a pow(1.0/3.0)?
        pub static ref cbrt_33_mul_3: f64 = 3.0 * 33.0f64.powf(0.5);
        
        pub static ref tribonacci_constant: f64 = 1.0
        + (19.0 - *cbrt_33_mul_3).powf(1.0 / 3.0)
        + (19.0 + *cbrt_33_mul_3).powf(1.0 / 3.0);
    }

    pub fn tribonacci(n: f64) -> f64 {
        return (
            (*tribonacci_constant / 3.0).powf(n)
            / (
                (4.0 / 3.0)
                * *tribonacci_constant
                - (1.0 / 9.0)
                * tribonacci_constant.powf(2.0) - 1.0
            )
        ).round();
    }

}

pub mod hc {
    pub fn tribonacci(n: f64) -> f64 {
        let p = super::constants::tribonacci::P;
        let s = super::constants::tribonacci::S;
        return (s * p.powf(n)).round();
    }
}
```

**benches/my_benchmark.rs**

```
use criterion::{black_box, criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion};
use rust_gen_const_vs_lazy_static::ls;
use rust_gen_const_vs_lazy_static::hc;

fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    c.bench_function("trib 5.1 ls", |b| b.iter(|| ls::tribonacci(black_box(5.1))));
    c.bench_function("trib 5.1 hc", |b| b.iter(|| hc::tribonacci(black_box(5.1))));
}

criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "rust_gen_const_vs_lazy_static"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
"lazy_static" = "1.4.0"

[dev-dependencies]
criterion = "0.3"

[[bench]]
name = "my_benchmark"
harness = false
```

**$OUTDIR/constants.rs** (generated)

```
pub mod tribonacci {
pub const P: f64 = 1.83928675521416096216853475198150;
pub const S: f64 = 0.33622811699494109527464047459944;
}
```

---

As suggested by Dilshod Tadjibaev it is possible to achieve a similar result using proc-macros, though it requires a little more work in this case. This gives exactly the same speed as build-time generation.

To set this up I created a new crate for the macros `trib_macros`, as proc-macros need to be in their own crate. This new crate contained just two files `Cargo.toml` and `src/lib.rs`

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "trib_macros"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"


[lib]
proc-macro = true
```

**src/lib.rs**

```
extern crate proc_macro;
use proc_macro::TokenStream;

#[proc_macro]
pub fn tp(_item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let cbrt_33_mul_3: f64 = 3.0 * 33.0f64.powf(0.5);
    
    let tribonacci_constant: f64 = 1.0 
        + (19.0 - cbrt_33_mul_3).powf(1.0 / 3.0)
        + (19.0 + cbrt_33_mul_3).powf(1.0 / 3.0);

    let p = tribonacci_constant / 3.0;
    format!("{}f64",p).parse().unwrap()
}

#[proc_macro]
pub fn ts(_item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let cbrt_33_mul_3: f64 = 3.0 * 33.0f64.powf(0.5);
    
    let tribonacci_constant: f64 = 1.0 
        + (19.0 - cbrt_33_mul_3).powf(1.0 / 3.0)
        + (19.0 + cbrt_33_mul_3).powf(1.0 / 3.0);

    let s = 1.0 / (
        (4.0 / 3.0)
        * tribonacci_constant
        - (1.0 / 9.0)
        * tribonacci_constant.powf(2.0) - 1.0
    );
    format!("{}f64",s).parse().unwrap()
}
```

Then we need to adjust the `Cargo.toml` of the original crate to pull this in.

```
[dependencies]
...
trib_macros = { path = "path/to/trib_macros" }
```

And finally using it is relatively clean:

```
pub mod mc {
    use trib_macros::{ts,tp};

    pub fn tribonacci(n: f64) -> f64 {
        return (ts!() * tp!().powf(n)).round();
    }
}
```

There's definitely a neater way to output the float literal tokens, but I couldn't find it.

---

You can find a complete repository for these tests at https://github.com/mikeando/rust_code_gen_example

Comment: First of all, you caught my small bug, I double-checked the math, it was a sqrt, not a cbrt. Fixed the variable naming. I had actually come back after testing lazy_static to report just that: after checking the output code, the numbers were all generated at compile-time, the code only contained constants, a call to powf, and a division operation. Thus, lazy_static and dereferencing actually resulted in worse code.

@Netwave

Comment: I'm looking for a way the achieve performance whether or not the compiler could optimize them to constants or not, without sacrificing code readability, developer effort, and such. I was surprised that there was not a simple, idiomatic way to do this.
I guess I am too used to using namespaced static constants in C++.

Comment: I agree that it's more effort to set this up (and constant float functions would be so much nicer and solve all of this), but once the pieces are in place it is pretty easy to maintain and scale.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson have you also looked solving this using macro?

Comment: @DilshodTadjibaev I assume you mean using something like `macro_rules! tribonacci_constant { () => ... }`? No, I haven't tried it - I guess there are no guarantees that the constant gets compiled in that case. (And I _suspect_ that it may not be possible for it to always be compiled down due to floating-point handling having to depend on various run-time flags)

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I meant having a macro function that can pre-compute values. Something along like this: const MY_CONST: f64 = macro_const_generator!(param1);

My use case is that I want to pre-compute table of sin values and store them in const array. I could use build script but I would like to parameterize, so macro can probably work. 

So you know, I opened SO question about using macro  but mods keep closing and referring to this post telling it's a duplicate question. But I would like to explore a solution with a macro.

Comment: @DilshodTadjibaev I don't believe there is a (sensible) macro-based way that can guarantee avoiding runtime calculations. At least not without resorting to what would essentially be reimplementing the basic mathematical functions (like pow) within the macro, in which case you'd be better or implementing const versions of the basic functions you need and using them instead.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson you might be right on this because I haven't tried it. However, from my recent reading, procedural macro allows running arbitrary code during build and has the same privs as build.rs  (https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#procedural-macros). Could this feature be relatively new? (https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/12/21/Procedural-Macros-in-Rust-2018.html). I'll give a try and post my solution here if it works. Thank you again.

Comment: I think you are right. You can probably do it with `proc_macro`s, just not regular macros. However, proc-macros come with the downside that they require you to create an additional crate to house your proc-macros in.

Comment: I did get it working with a proc-macro and have added it as a further example.

Comment: Thank you very much for updating your solution with a macro version. This is awesome!

Comment: I'd like to add the `build` and `proc_macro` methods only work if the type can be written as a literal, well the question was for `f64` which does but the title is not limited to f64, for example I was looking for a way to do this for `SocketAddr`, which unfortunately can't be written as a literal since it has private fields, and const `SocketAddr::new()` is not stable yet.

Comment: @JimmyZ This approach is specifically for performance tweaking where the constant is used in a hot loop. If you're not working with a primitive, or the constants are not used in a hot-loop, then it is unlikely that the overhead of using `lazy_static` matters. So just use that approach.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson yeah sure I'm not expecting to use `SocketAddr` in a hot loop, that's just an example though, I don't really have a better example but I'm sure "needed in a hot loop" and "can't be written as a literal" aren't exclusive to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`lazy_static`](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/1.4.0/lazy_static/):

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static; // 1.4.0

lazy_static! {
    static ref cbrt_33_mul_3: f64 = 3.0 * 33.0f64.powf(0.5);
    
    static ref tribonacci_constant: f64 = 1.0
    + (19.0 - *cbrt_33_mul_3).powf(1.0 / 3.0)
    + (19.0 + *cbrt_33_mul_3).powf(1.0 / 3.0);
}

fn tribonacci(n: f64) -> f64 {
    return (
        (*tribonacci_constant / 3.0).powf(n)
        / (
            (4.0 / 3.0)
            * *tribonacci_constant
            - (1.0 / 9.0)
            * tribonacci_constant.powf(2.0) - 1.0
        )
    ).round();
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Note the usage of `ref` and the dereference needed for the `tribonacci_constant`.