# How to pre-compute values and assign to a constant

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I need a way to pre-compute values and assign to a constant. I know there is const function but unfortunately currently this does not work for me because I am using complex math expressions with sin, cos, log, etc functions. I am open to using rust macro or build functionality if this is possible.

UPDATE:
To clarify my question. The input for the math functions are simply numeric constants and the output is an array. Basically I want to generate a look up table with values from a mathematical expression. For example, if I want to look up a value for sin(n), where n in [0:100] and n would correspond to index as 1:1, then I would simply look up like TABLE[n].

One option I can use is to generate rust code with some a helper script. Other options are const function or macro!. Const function does not work because math functions are not written with const.

lazy_static does not work for my example. Besides I am using no_std.

Comment: Can you edit your question to say more about what the inputs (if any) to your computation are and what the type of the output is? Both macros and `build.rs` could do this but one option might be better than another.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize immutable globals with non-const initializer in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65120456/how-to-initialize-immutable-globals-with-non-const-initializer-in-rust) it is an example of doing this both using a build.rs file, and using lazy-static for the tribonacci sequence.

Comment: This question is incorrectly closed and directed to "How to initialize immutable globals with non-const initializer in Rust?" but it's wrong answer. This question should be reopened.

Comment: As I mentioned on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67427742/3650362) the closure is not incorrect because the answer to the linked question also covers how to do it without `lazy_static`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not strictly what you are looking for, but might be an acceptable alternative:

The [`lazy_static`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) crates allows you to define values/objects that are only computed once.
The computation happens at runtime, so it is not free. However, since const functions and values are still limited, this allows you to at least amortize the cost of computation.